# Changing brightness/contrast of a specific window?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

There is an API for changing the brightness and contrast of the screen, yet I am unable to find any relative API to change these properties for a window from another application.

Is there an API which can change the brightness/contrast of a window from another application?

Comment: There is no such API

Comment: As far as I know, there are no screens that have brightness and contrast settings for individual pixels.

Comment: There is no such API because it wouldn't be useful. The Windows Color System infrastructure solves the issue of compensating for physical properties of display devices. The API is thus based off of devices. By contrast, if a hypothetical API on a per-window basis existed, what should the result be if the target window were to straddle physical display devices?

Comment: @IInspectable actually such an API would a low a whole a lot of new possibilities for tools and accessibility options on multi-screen setups.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev I'm not sure what useful feature an API would provide that cannot be made to work across displays. If you need to need to set color adjustments for individual display devices, then that is a different API (incidentally, that one exists).

Comment: @IInspectable nope. Display related API is limiting the possibilities. For instance - if You have 3 monitor setup, and You have an applications which comes and goes around, and you place them in specific monitor for a specific reason, and they are not taking the full space, but just a few as in my case on 3 x 50" screens - a specific application or game could be much darker and giving you bad experience using it trough the day. With such an API this could be easily fixed from 3rd party application listing and managing the brightness of application in a list it could have.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev If you are confident that you have discovered an undue limitation of an API, there's nothing stopping you from submitting a Design Change Request to Microsoft. Make sure that your value proposition explains why a niche use case warrants exhibiting undesirable results for the majority of use cases, including those required by professional video editors.

Comment: @IInspectable not sure where to submit such a request tbh.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev  I'd suggest you could submit a feedback/feature request about this API/feature in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**->**API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.